# jQuery library doesn't load from google

Tags: jquery

I want to load jQuery from Google, but it always fails to load. What is wrong in my source code?

Mistake

```
(X) GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content='IE=8' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
    <title></title> 
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>console.log($('body').height());</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: To the people who voted to close: this is a perfectly reproducible issue and it is not a typographical error, this is a common issue and source of confusion with protocol relative URLs and local development.  Don't vote to close questions if you don't understand enough about what you are reading to make that call.

Comment: @Ennui You said it. This question is perfectly within SO Rules/Guidelines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are testing the file locally.

Change

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Add comment @[Ennui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600854/ennui)

To explain, `//` is a protocol relative url, so on localhost it will be interpreted as `file://`, on http as `http://` and over SSL as `https://`. This is useful on sites that combine http and https protocols, but can get confusing when used on a local development site.

Comment: To explain, `//` is a protocol relative url, so on localhost it will be interpreted as `file://`, on http as `http://` and over SSL as `https://`.  This is useful on sites that combine `http` and `https` protocols, but can get confusing when used on a local development site.